# superclass' methods not available

Tags: sapui5

Most docs on the init method of UI5 components mention to call the superclass' `init` method when overwriting it:

```js
sap.ui.commons.Button.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
```

But this is not working. When debugging `sap.ui.commonds.Button` and analyzing its prototype, there's [no `init` method present](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/3d731d70a293f229f2992c7567cd4d3d997dd3a0/src/sap.ui.commons/src/sap/ui/commons/Button.js) - so of course `apply` fails.

Am I doing anything wrong or is this a deprecated approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the UI5 documentation:

> If you inherit from another control that has (**or might get**) an init() method, you need to explicitly call it...

Since the Button control has no init() function so far (but can exist in future versions) I would do it like this to be future safe:

```
 if (sap.ui.commons.Button.prototype.init) {   // check whether superclass has an init() method
  sap.ui.commons.Button.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);  // call super.init()
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the [commit `e9fb3c1`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/e9fb3c1288c592985afc3e387a09f82e18f671b8) by Jonathan Brink, this is no longer an issue since OpenUI5 version 1.54.0 (SAPUI5 1.54.2). Checking the existence of the `init`, `onBeforeRendering`, `onAfterRendering`, and `exit` in the superclass is not required anymore.

```js
init: function() {
  MyRequiredSuperControl.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
  // ...
},
```

Simply call `init.apply` without `if`.